# PDF Low Level - Defining EXACT text glyph coordinates on the page

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I need to define the exact individual width, height and coordinates for each character in the content stream of a PDF.

I can't figure out how to do this. I want to completely ignore any rules about the width, height, positioning, etc. and just draw the glyphs exactly as I want them, where I want them.

How can I do this?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You can position the text exactly using the TRM command but will need to have a clear understanding of the fontBounds on eaxch glyph to achieve what you want.